# Eloquent R solution to change multiple row values based on one row value

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, case

I am cleaning a 200 row survey dataset. The survey used quite a bit of branching and is returning NAs for cases where the participant did not receive the question so it is throwing off my missing data analysis. I have spent a day and a half trying to figure out an eloquent solution (for loops, if conditions, filter(dplyr), mutate(dplyr), case_when). I settled on a solution using `mutate()` but I know there's a better way to do this.

Here's a reproducible data frame to act as the survey data

```
df <- data.frame(attsess1 = c(1, 1, 1, -99, -99), attsess2 = c(-99, -99, 1, 1, 1), s1satis = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA), s1time = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA), s1qual = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA), s2satis = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1), s2time = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1))
```

Essentially, if attsess1 equals -99 then I want the following corresponding rows in s1satis, s1time, s1qual to change their NAs to -99. Same logic applies to attsess2 and s2satis and s2time.

The code below is what I used. It works but it takes too many lines and this could be problematic for large datasets with a lot of variables

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% mutate(s1satis = case_when(attsess1 == -99 ~ -99)) %>% mutate(s1time  = case_when(attsess1 == -99 ~ -99)) %>% mutate(s1qual = case_when(attsess1 == -99 ~ -99)) %>% mutate(s2satis = case_when(attsess2 == -99 ~ -99)) %>% mutate(s2time = case_when(attsess2 == -99 ~ -99))
```

I tried using `mutate_at` and `case_when`, but received this error message:

> must be a double vector, not an integer vector.

I also tried for loops nested with if conditions, but I can't remember the error message I received. I also came across several forums where the authors were advocating to replace for loops for dplyr functions.

Comment: Is it expected to change `1`s for `NA`s?

Comment: Hi Markus, it's expected to change NA for -99. Does this answer your question

Comment: In your example `attsess1` is `1, 1, 1, -99, -99`. `s1satis` starts as `1, 1, 1, NA, NA`. Based on your description, I would expect the desired result for `s1satis` to be `1, 1, 1, -99, -99`, replacing the NA with -99 where attsess1 is -99 and leaving the `1` values untouched. But when I run your "working but slow" code, I get `NA, NA, NA, -99, -99`. Which is the right answer?

Comment: Gregor, you're right-- the 1s should be untouched. Your expected result is correct and not the code I have (which is annoying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `dplyr` version is updated and this idea should work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("s1"), ~ case_when(attsess1 == -99 ~ -99, TRUE ~ .)),
    across(starts_with("s2"), ~ case_when(attsess2 == -99 ~ -99, TRUE ~ .))
  )

#   attsess1 attsess2 s1satis s1time s1qual s2satis s2time
# 1        1      -99       1      1      1     -99    -99
# 2        1      -99       1      1      1     -99    -99
# 3        1        1       1      1     NA      NA      1
# 4      -99        1     -99    -99    -99       1      1
# 5      -99        1     -99    -99    -99       1      1
```

Though I'm not really sure about your desired result, see my comment on your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. Yes, my code provided was incorrect (which is embarrassing on my end).

Comment: Glad to hear! If this answers your question, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark in the left margin next to the answer.

Comment: The code above worked on the toy data, but does not work on my actual data. Here's the error code provided in the console: *Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. x must be a double vector, not an integer vector.ℹ Input `..1` is `across(...)`.*  I checked the data type and the toy data is double and my actual data is classified as integer. I tried using the as.double() function for my variables but they still return as integers. Any insight, because your code above is nice and short.

Comment: If *all* the relevant columns are integer, then changing `-99` to `-99L` should work (`-99` is a double, `-99L` is an integer). Alternately, convert all the integer columns to regular numeric first, `across(where(is.integer), as.numeric)` as the first thing inside the `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take an entire dataset and replace all `NA`s with -99, you can use this:

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), -99))
```